# Apex SOAP WebService - how to suppress/alter accepted header

Tags: apex, webservices, soap, apex-webservice

I am working with a 3rd party on SOAP integration, and they send a detailed async fault response to any POST done by us. The data they send is rigid and they say they cannot (or won't) change it.

I am receiving an error on a "mustUnderstand":

```
soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Did not understand header {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12}Signature</faultstring>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

As well as their namespace on the fault.

```
<B:Fault>
 <B:faultcode>xxxxxxx</B:faultcode>
 <B:faultstring>xxxxxxxx</B:faultstring>
 <B:detail>
    <faultdetails>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</faultdetails>
 </B:detail>
</B:Fault>
```

Error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>No operation available for request {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}fault, please check the WSDL for the service.</faultstring>
       </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I already have to use a force.com site for unauthenticated posts, but is there anyway I can change the namespace that Salesforce allows as well as ignore the MustUnderstand?

Edit. Even this call is invalid:

```
<B:Envelope xmlns:B="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-SEC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12">
   </SOAP:Header>
   <B:Body id="Body">
       <B:fault>
          <faultcode>Hello</faultcode>
          <faultstring>World!</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <faultdetails>A corresponding parent message could not be located. </faultdetails>
          </detail>
        </B:fault>
   </B:Body>
</B:Envelope>
```

I have to apply my namespace "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/myApexClass" to the fault block. So I am not sure how it would work. Note: this isn't is synchronous response

Comment: Personally, it feels like their SOAP implementation is not SOAP-compliant, and they're trying to cover this up somehow. The namespace should not matter if it is declared properly (`xmlns:B="some-namespace-url"`). There's not much you can do if they're not actually SOAP compliant except to write your own HttpRequest-based implementation.

Comment: The namespace for B is "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
If I add another namespace "xmlns:Q="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/myApexClass" and use that in the Fault block instead of B, it works fine.

Comment: @sfdcfox Even the call listed in the Edit is invalid. returns:
<faultstring>No operation available for request {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}fault, please check the WSDL for the service.</faultstring>